# Gre combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

In a local election there are $2$ candidates for mayor, $4$ candidates for sheriff, and $5$ candidates for dogcatcher on the ballot. In each of the three categories a voter may vote for exactly one candidate or none. How many different ways can a voter fill out the ballot?

I don't think I understand the question, but I do feel like it's a combinatorics question.

Have been working for like 8 hours on practice questions and my mind is absolutely slow at the moment. In particular, I'm not sure what it means by "In each of the three categories a voter may vote for exactly one candidate or none" then we can count the different ways from it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It means that a voter may vote for at most one of the $2$ candidates for mayor, at most one of the $4$ candidates for sheriff, and at most $1$ of the $5$ candidates for dogcatcher. Thus, a voter has $3$ choice for mayor: one candidate, the other candidate, or none. Similarly for the other two offices.

Comment: Can the voter turn in a completely blank ballot?  By the conditions above, it doesn't say they can't, but it is possible that the test designer means to disallow that possibility.

Comment: @DougM if blank ballot disallowed, simply subtract 1 from otherwise computed value.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $3\times 5\times 6 = \boxed{90}$ since the voter has to make three independent decisions. The first decision requires the voter to choose between one of three options (vote for nobody, vote for the first candidate, or vote for the second candidate). The other two cases are similar.